# script time out, even when there seems to be no issue with code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a new to this and it is becoming frustrating to be stuck for the past couple of days I would be glad to have your inputs on my piece of code, it is a google script that has run well for quite some time but i guess the data is becoming bigger and my function times out every time it is triggered. I can not seem to understand how to optimise it.

I have a loop where iterations happen and I am looking for ways to reduce th run time

```
type here
```

```
function Serio() {
const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ssSetting = sss.getSheetByName('Labs');
var tss = sss.getSheetByName("Finished");

var clearseriosh = sss.getSheetByName("Serio");
clearseriosh.getRange(2, 1,clearseriosh.getLastRow(), clearseriosh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();


const serioLabs = tss.getRange("M2:M").getValues(); 
const seriotag = tss.getRange("J2:J").getValues();
const serioprod = tss.getRange("L2:L").getValues();
const ts = sss.getSheetByName('Serio');
for (var i = 0; i < seriolabs.length; i++) {
  try{
    if(seriolabs[i][0] != '' &&seriolabs [i][0] != '#REF'){
      var shellunitlink = seriolabs[i][0];
      var shellunitId = shellunitlink.substring(xx,xx);
      var tag = seriotag[i];
      var prod = serioprod [i];
      const sourcesheetSerio =  SpreadsheetApp.openById(shellunitId);   
      const sourceSerio = sourcesheetSerio.getSheetByName("Arrivals");
      const ts = sss.getSheetByName('Serio');
      if(sourceSerio){      
      const rawData = sourceSerio.getRange("C2:I").getValues().map(([
      A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I]) => ["Serio",tag,prod,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,shellunitlink]);
      const rrawData=rawData.filter(row=>row[0]=="Serio" && row[1]==tag && row[2]==prod && row[3]!=""&& row[4]=="toxic");
      if(rrawData.length > 0 ){
      ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, rrawData.length,13).setValues(rrawData);
     }
           const rrawData1=rawData.filter(row=>row[0]=="Serio" && row[1]==tag && row[2]==prod && row[3]!=""&& row[4]=="NA");
      if(rrawData1.length > 0 ){
      ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, rrawData1.length,13).setValues(rrawData1);
     }
           const rrawData2=rawData.filter(row=>row[0]=="Serio" && row[1]==tag && row[2]==prod && row[3]!=""&& row[4]=="eco");
      if(rrawData2.length > 0 ){
      ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, rrawData2.length,13).setValues(rrawData2);
     }
     }
    }}
    catch(e) {
  continue;//If error continue looping
   }}
  
  }
```

Comment: First of all you need to correct your typos.  The first one I found is `serioLabs` but later you use `seriolabs` every where else.  Variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: @ThewWizEd, thank you for the suggestions, I made the typo correction, and I trigerred a manual execution already,  I hope it executes

Comment: Using ranges like this `const serioLabs = tss.getRange("M2:M").getValues(); ` is a bad idea because you end up with a lot of nulls at the end of the data set.

Comment: I recommend that you get some help rewriting your code.  I can't really say much more without getting in trouble from the answer police.

Comment: @cooper thanks for your comments, unfortunately there is no known end to the range actually because I do not know the number of cells that will get populated before the next trigger so I could not close the range.   If you have suggestions to do that it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test it, and I hope I caught all my typos, etc.  But I think this will work.

I typically use indices into the value array rather than define individual varaibles.

First, I get all the values from sheet into `seriosValues`, remove the header.

Then, I filter each sheets column A !== "".  Then I concatinate the tag and prod and to the row values.  Filter each "toxic", "NA" and "eco" group.  The `catch return` is the same as `continue` in a for loop.

Now that I have collected all rows into `rrawData` I write to the spreadsheet.

```
function Serio() {

  let sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let ssSetting = sss.getSheetByName('Labs');
  let tss = sss.getSheetByName("Finished");

  let ts = sss.getSheetByName("Serio");
  ts.getRange(2, 1,ts.getLastRow(), ts.getLastColumn()).clearContent();

  let seriosValues = tss.getDataRange().getValues();
  seriosValues.shift(); // remove headers
  let rawData = [];
  let rrawData = [];
  seriosValuesforEach( seriosRow => {
      if( ( seriosRow[0] !== "" ) && ( seriosRow[0] !== "#REF" ) ) {
        let shellunitId = seriosRow[0].substring(xx,xx);
        try {
          let sourcesheetSerio =  SpreadsheetApp.openById(shellunitId);   
          let sourceSerio = sourcesheetSerio.getSheetByName("Arrivals");
          if( sourceSerio ) {
            rawData = sourceSerio.getRange(2,3,sourceSerio.getLastRow()-1,9).getValues();
            rawData = rawData.filter( rawRow => rawRow[0] !== "" );  // filter A !== ""
            rawData = rawData.map( rawRow => ["Serio",tag,prod].concat(rawRow,seriosRow[0]) );
            // all rows or rawData have "Serio",tag,prod
            rawData.forEach( rawRow => {
                if( rawRow[4] === "toxic" ) rrawData.push(rawRow);
              }
            );
            rawData.forEach( rawRow => {
                if( rawRow[4] === "NA" ) rrawData.push(rawRow);
              }
            );
            rawData.forEach( rawRow => {
                if( rawRow[4] === "eco" ) rrawData.push(rawRow);
              }
            );
          }
        }
        catch(err) {
          Logger.log("Error in Serio: "+err);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  );
  if( rrawData.length > 0 ) {
    ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, rrawData.length,13).setValues(rrawData);
  }
}
```